# Jquery function not working on the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have added function for datepicker. but my date picker is not open on the first click.
here is my jsp code..

To 

here is my query functions..

```
            function addDate(idName) {
                    $(idName).datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1,
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
                });
            }function addTime(idName) {
                $(idName).timepicker({`
                    ampm: true,
                    timeFormat: "hh:mmtt"
                });
            }
```

please help me.. thanks.

Comment: how is `addDate()` called

Comment: why dont you paste the complete jquery code along with the jsp code. if possible add a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net. while adding code to fiddle, use the rendered html code , because it doesnt support server scripts

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle and share it in your question. It would help people understand the context better I think.

Comment: i share it on http://jsfiddle.net/AM5JZ/4/ . please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

DatePickers and TimePickers are assigned to focus events automatically. You do not need to call `$(object).datepicker()` every time, just at initialization and it will open properly when focused.

A good approach is to assign the **.datepicker** class to every object you want to have the DatePicker assigned and, then, assign the DatePicker to all elements of that class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    });
});
```

Do the same thing with TimePickers.

Comment: thanks Alejandro Iván. how can i call this function in jsp page?

Comment: Hmm not sure, I don't use JavaServer pages. Anyway, this is Javascript, not Java. Just output this inside an HTML <script> tag and it should word. This script is run locally on visitor's computer, not on server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bellow and i don know  what language your using?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.Filters.EndTime,new { @class = "date" })
$('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd", maxDate: '+0d', minDate: '-600d'});
```

above code is written in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
addDate(idName)
```

on document ready like this

```
$(function() {
 addDate(idName)
});
```

Comment: i tried this method. but it is not working. this is what i have tried. $(function addDate(idName) {
    
  $(idName).datepicker();
                
                
 }); in jsp <input type="Text"  id="datepicker" maxlength="25" placeholder="Add event Date and Time" size="10" name="datepicker"  style ="height:15px;" onclick="addDate(datepicker);"/>